# How would you reorder an ID column after row deletion? [Postgresql]

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, sequence, alter

I have a table such as

| id | material |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | steel |
| 3 | copper |
| 4 | nickel |

The id column is a bigserial,

```
CREATE TABLE material (
id bigserial PRIMARY KEY...);
```

When I try to reset the sequence and update the id column,

```
ALTER SEQUENCE id_seq RESTART;
UPDATE material SET id = DEFAULT;
```

I get the following error:

duplicate key value violates unique constraint "private key"

DETAIL: Key (id)=(2) already exists

How do I go about updating my id column?

Comment: Why? A sequence is just a number generator it is not guaranteed to be gapless or really even have meaning. If you are looking for that,  this is the wrong approach as you will be repeating it on a regular basis.

Comment: As to why you got the error you will need to update your question with the output of `\d output`. I suspect you have another constraint on `id`.

Comment: the **only** job for a primary key is to be unique. It is completely irrelevant if that value is 1,2, 42, 76586 or -45342. There is nothing you need to do or should do. Just move on

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that is not true. If the PK is a natural key it can convey information beyond uniqueness.